# Two dropdown menus, one left, one right, in the same toggle menu (responsive)

Tags: menuitem

I cant figure this out on my own so I'm begging you for help. I need a responsive menu, which is two drop down menus in one when you are on mobile/ipad. For example, one of the menu is on the top of the website to the left, and the second one to the right. When you resize the window and make it smaller, it will appear under each other in a toggled menu. I need the menu to be fixed when it is showing on the computer, I need it to follow when it scrolls down. I will show you an example of how the two dropdown menus look (this is not my website, but I need one like this but responsive and toggled when the screen becomes smaller):

[image]

EDIT: I managed to find one at getbootstrap.com but I want the submenu to show up when I hover it. Right now I'm forced to click on the menu to see the submenu, and I don't want that. The codes can be found at

`jsfiddle.net/6poubg32/2/`

Comment: Please show us what you have tried to achieve this, so we could help you with problems that might occur during this, instead of giving you the "product" itself

Comment: Welcome to SO. Can you provide some information about the technology that you are using so people can help you?

Comment: I managed to find one at getbootstrap.com but I want the submenu to show up when I hover it. Right now i'm forced to click on the menu to see the submenu, and I dont want that.. I put my codes above!

Answer (score 0):

just try adding small JQuery Hover function on your menu `<li>` or `<ul>` tags.

```
$( "your_menu_button_id" ).hover(function() {
     // logic to show your menu example call toggle function
     // you can also add css class which opens the menu. 
     $( "#foo" ).addClass( "myClass yourClass" ); 
     // or use this to toggle the classes
     $( "#foo" ).toggleClass( className, addOrRemove );
});
```

other examples can be found [here-> for hover function](http://api.jquery.com/hover/)
for dynamically adding class use this [link](http://api.jquery.com/addclass/) & this [link](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) for toggleClass to understand more.

Hope this helps.!

Comment: Oh well, I learned some now and managed it to work! Thank you so much! =)

Comment: One up if my answer helped.